# Getting IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

the obscure exception is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run1.py", line 44, in <module>
    bl = list(bl_trees)
  File "/home/zal/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 731, in next
    raise value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

A shortened version of the code is:

```
i = 0
for workload in workloads:
   print(workload)
   for M, dM in [(1000, 50)]:
     print(M, dM)

try:
  print("Baseline.")
  bl_trees = LSMulator.cache_vs_bloom_vs_buf_threaded(workload, M, dM=dM, balloc=baseline_assignment, verbose=True)
  bl = list(bl_trees)
  for t in bl:
    t.clear_data()
  with open('./results-{}-{}-{}-{}.pkl'.format(str(workload), M, dM, "bl"), 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump((str(workload), M, dM, bl), f)
except Exception as ex:
  traceback.print_exc()

try:
  print("Monkey.")
  mk_trees = LSMulator.cache_vs_bloom_vs_buf_threaded(workload, M, dM=dM, balloc=monkey_assignment, verbose=True)
  mk = list(mk_trees)
  for t in mk:
    t.clear_data()
  with open('./results-{}-{}-{}-{}.pkl'.format(str(workload), M, dM, "mk"), 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump((str(workload), M, dM, mk), f)
except Exception as ex:
  traceback.print_exc()

i += 1
```

this is the complete code:

```
from lsmulator import *
from workloads import *
from bloom_assignments import *
from workloads import *
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
import dill as pickle
import traceback

n = 50000
k = 5000

workloads = [
  UniformWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k),
  RoundRobinWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k),
  ZipfWorkload(n_queries=n, zipf_param=1.1),
  ZipfWorkload(n_queries=n, zipf_param=1.5),
  ZipfWorkload(n_queries=n, zipf_param=1.8),
  EightyTwentyWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k),
  EightyTwentyWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k, update_fraction=0.25),
  EightyTwentyWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k, update_fraction=0.65),
  MultinomialWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k),
  MultinomialWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k, dist=scipy.stats.gamma(2)),
  MultinomialWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k, dist=scipy.stats.expon(1)),
  DiscoverDecayWorkload(n_queries=n),
  DiscoverDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, lookups=scipy.stats.poisson(8)),
  DiscoverDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, decay_rate=scipy.stats.beta(2, 1)),
  DiscoverDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, updates=scipy.stats.poisson(0), decay_rate=scipy.stats.beta(2, 1)),
  DiscoverDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, updates=scipy.stats.poisson(16), decay_rate=scipy.stats.beta(2, 1)),
  PeriodicDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, period=100),
  PeriodicDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, period=1000),
  PeriodicDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, period=1000, decay_rate=scipy.stats.beta(2, 1))
]

i = 0
for workload in workloads:
  print(workload)
  for M, dM in [(1000, 50)]:
    print(M, dM)

    try:
      print("Baseline.")
      bl_trees = LSMulator.cache_vs_bloom_vs_buf_threaded(workload, M, dM=dM, balloc=baseline_assignment, verbose=True)
      bl = list(bl_trees)
      for t in bl:
        t.clear_data()
      with open('./results-{}-{}-{}-{}.pkl'.format(str(workload), M, dM, "bl"), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump((str(workload), M, dM, bl), f)
    except Exception as ex:
      traceback.print_exc()

    try:
      print("Monkey.")
      mk_trees = LSMulator.cache_vs_bloom_vs_buf_threaded(workload, M, dM=dM, balloc=monkey_assignment, verbose=True)
      mk = list(mk_trees)
      for t in mk:
        t.clear_data()
      with open('./results-{}-{}-{}-{}.pkl'.format(str(workload), M, dM, "mk"), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump((str(workload), M, dM, mk), f)
    except Exception as ex:
      traceback.print_exc()

    i += 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code is no [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we are unable to reproduce the error. This kind of error happens if you access a list beyond its length: `c= [1,2,3]` && `print(c[8])`. Please provide a MVCE or use [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to find your error.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with just the two lines `bl_trees = LSMulator...` and `bl = list(bl_trees)`? If so, what is `bl_trees`?

Comment: this is the code link  https://github.com/asross/cs265/blob/master/simulations/run1.py

Comment: It depends upon what `LSMulator.cache_vs_bloom_vs_buf_threaded` returns. What is `LSMulator` is it your own code or a library?

Comment: LSMulator is my own code ,the code link https://github.com/asross/cs265/blob/master/simulations/lsmulator.py

Answer (score 0):

this is the complete code:

```
from lsmulator import *
from workloads import *
from bloom_assignments import *
from workloads import *
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
import dill as pickle
import traceback

n = 50000
k = 5000

workloads = [
  UniformWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k),
  RoundRobinWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k),
  ZipfWorkload(n_queries=n, zipf_param=1.1),
  ZipfWorkload(n_queries=n, zipf_param=1.5),
  ZipfWorkload(n_queries=n, zipf_param=1.8),
  EightyTwentyWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k),
  EightyTwentyWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k, update_fraction=0.25),
  EightyTwentyWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k, update_fraction=0.65),
  MultinomialWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k),
  MultinomialWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k, dist=scipy.stats.gamma(2)),
  MultinomialWorkload(n_queries=n, k_classes=k, dist=scipy.stats.expon(1)),
  DiscoverDecayWorkload(n_queries=n),
  DiscoverDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, lookups=scipy.stats.poisson(8)),
  DiscoverDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, decay_rate=scipy.stats.beta(2, 1)),
  DiscoverDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, updates=scipy.stats.poisson(0), decay_rate=scipy.stats.beta(2, 1)),
  DiscoverDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, updates=scipy.stats.poisson(16), decay_rate=scipy.stats.beta(2, 1)),
  PeriodicDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, period=100),
  PeriodicDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, period=1000),
  PeriodicDecayWorkload(n_queries=n, period=1000, decay_rate=scipy.stats.beta(2, 1))
]

i = 0
for workload in workloads:
  print(workload)
  for M, dM in [(1000, 50)]:
    print(M, dM)

    try:
      print("Baseline.")
      bl_trees = LSMulator.cache_vs_bloom_vs_buf_threaded(workload, M, dM=dM, balloc=baseline_assignment, verbose=True)
      bl = list(bl_trees)
      for t in bl:
        t.clear_data()
      with open('./results-{}-{}-{}-{}.pkl'.format(str(workload), M, dM, "bl"), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump((str(workload), M, dM, bl), f)
    except Exception as ex:
      traceback.print_exc()

    try:
      print("Monkey.")
      mk_trees = LSMulator.cache_vs_bloom_vs_buf_threaded(workload, M, dM=dM, balloc=monkey_assignment, verbose=True)
      mk = list(mk_trees)
      for t in mk:
        t.clear_data()
      with open('./results-{}-{}-{}-{}.pkl'.format(str(workload), M, dM, "mk"), 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump((str(workload), M, dM, mk), f)
    except Exception as ex:
      traceback.print_exc()

    i += 1
```

Comment: this is the code link https://github.com/asross/cs265/blob/master/simulations/run1.py

Comment: All this stuff may be useful, but the place to put it is in the question.